# jquery: how to hide tables depending on text input

Tags: jquery, filter, html-table

I have one text input box

```
<input type="text" id="search" />
```

and **multiple HTML-tables** like this:

```
<table id="table1">
<thead>
        <tr>
                <th>Table1 title</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
        <tr>
                <td>Andrew</td>
                <td>USA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to filter data depending on what user types in the input box.

Now my JS code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#search").keyup(function(){
        // When value of the input is not blank
        if( $(this).val() != "")
        {
                // Show only matching TR, hide rest of them
                $("#table1 > tbody > tr").hide();
                $("#table1 td:contains-ci('" + $(this).val() + "')").parent("tr").show();
         } else {
                // When there is no input or clean again, show everything back
                $("#table1 tbody > tr").show();
                }
        });
});

// jQuery expression for case-insensitive filter
$.extend($.expr[":"],
{
        "contains-ci": function(elem, i, match, array)
        {
                return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || $(elem).text() || "").toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
        }
});
```

Everything works OK.

But now I want to hide a whole table including thead TR's if a typed text is not in the table.

How can I get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this <kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jrfUM/)</kbd>

```
     $("#search").keyup(function () {
    var txtVal = $(this).val();
    if (txtVal != "") {
        $(".tblDetails").show();
        $(".message").remove();
        $.each($('.tblDetails'), function (i, o) {
            var match = $("td:contains-ci('" + txtVal + "')", this);
            if (match.length > 0) $(match).parent("tr").show();
            else $(this).hide();
        });
    } else {
        // When there is no input or clean again, show everything back
        $("tbody > tr", this).show();
    }
    if($('.tblDetails:visible').length == 0)
    {
        $('#search').after('<p class="message">Sorry No results found!!!</p>');
    }
});

// jQuery expression for case-insensitive filter
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
    "contains-ci": function (elem, i, match, array) {
        return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || $(elem).text() || "").toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: But what if I have more than one table?

Comment: More than 1 table? I did nt get that. Could you explain the scenario.

Comment: Edited start post: got that info bolded.

Comment: I have multiple tables which may contain various information.
I have one input box.
When I type a text in that box I want to see only tables which contain that part of text.
If some tables does not contain that text, they have to be hidden including both <thead> and <tbody> section.

Comment: Updated the answer with Fiddle. Check it once you get a chance

Comment: I know it's been more than 2 years since last comment and am not sure about this sites grave digging policies, but is it possible that someone help me make modification to this so it only shows rows that match filter inside tables instead of entire table?