# Search/Filter rows through multiple tables with one search field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have PHP generated tables, usually more than 10 at a time. I want to use one search field to find rows that match input in all tables and show only those rows, but if there is no such row in a table then i want that table hidden.

I have found close answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16127730/3435158 that's doing great in hiding tables that don't have rows that match - however with his code entire table that matches search input stay visible, and I want only rows that match to be visible, not entire table.

---

edit: http://jsfiddle.net/jrfUM/113/

What I want to do is if I type 'andrew' in a search field, i want to get (*hopefully I'm more clear now*):

```
+---------+
| table 1 |
+---------+
| Andrew  |
+---------+

+---------+
| table 4 |
+---------+
| Andrew  |
+---------+
```

Comment: Have a look at datatables.js  https://www.datatables.net/ which has very useful sort and filter capability. If you go to the trouble of making a jsfiddle with the table and a start, I will add a vote to remove the -1 and give you help with the config.

Comment: Hm, i have pretty much exact problem as the guy in thread I linked in question, but ok, i'll make fiddles.

Comment: I hope you are looking for something like [this](http://anthonybush.com/projects/jquery_fast_live_filter/). It works on tables, lists.

Comment: @sahil It does work, but it leaves me with empty table where I only see header if there is no row that matches, it does not hide table completely if empty. In my fiddle example here, i'd get table 1 - Andrew // Table 2 // Table 3 // Table 4 - Andrew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to edit [PSL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1009603/psl) [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127673/jquery-how-to-hide-tables-depending-on-text-input/16127730#16127730) and made it work for what I needed: http://jsfiddle.net/jrfUM/115/

```
<input type="text" id="search" />
<table class="tblDetails">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Table 1</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Andrew</td></tr>
        <tr><td>John</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="tblDetails">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Table 2</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Jack</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Marc</td></tr>
    </tbody>
 ....
```

---

```
$("#search").keyup(function () {
    var txtVal = $(this).val();
    if (txtVal != "") {
        $(".tblDetails").show();
        $(".message").remove();
        $.each($('.tblDetails'), function (i, o) {
            var match = $("td:contains-ci('" + txtVal + "')", this);
            match.parent().siblings().hide();                       //  <<=== [LINE ADD]
            if (match.length > 0) $(match).parent("tr").show();
            else $(this).hide();
        });
    } else {
        // When there is no input or clean again, show everything back
        $("tbody > tr", this).show();
    }
    if($('.tblDetails:visible').length == 0)
    {
        $('#search').after('<p class="message">Sorry No results found!!!</p>');
    }
});

// jQuery expression for case-insensitive filter
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
    "contains-ci": function (elem, i, match, array) {
        return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || $(elem).text() || "").toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: much better - possibly change `.keyup(function()` to `.change(function()` and move the `$(".message").remove();` to before the if statement, so that the message is always removed.  That way a bad search deleted would not then keep the error message (delete doesn't trigger keyup).